# Pasting range to other sheet with PasteSpecial causes Run Time Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste data from one sheet to another so, that data is parsed from different cells to one row, and that the amount of rows is dependent of the amount of rows in the variable "Devices".

One of the problems with this code is that if there is only one row of data that needs to be copied, I get the run-time error '1004', "You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size".

Other, bigger problem for me is that I can't use PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
when pasting only values from "Devices" to another sheet. .Paste works just fine.

This is the first time for me working with VBA, so I know that there are probably a ton of other problems in the code as well, but I'm trying to get there.

```
Dim Lastrow As Long

Dim OrderNr As Range
Dim Customer As Range
Dim Date As Range
Dim Devices As Range
Dim DeviceAmount As Integer
Dim q As Long

Set Customer = Range("A4")
Set OrderNr = Range("C5")
Set Date = Range("E5")
Set Devices = Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

'Count the amount of devices, and move the value to "DeviceAmount"-variable'

Worksheets("Laskentapohja").Activate

DeviceAmount = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row - 1

MsgBox ("Amount of devices is " & DeviceAmount)

'Find the first empty row of the target sheet, and paste devices into empty F-column cells' 

Worksheets("Laskentapohja").Activate
Devices.Select
Selection.Copy

    Lastrow = Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Range("F" & Lastrow).Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Paste

'Find the first empty row of the target sheet, and paste the customer name into first empty A-column cell times the amount of devices'

Worksheets("Laskentapohja").Activate
Customer.Select
Selection.Copy

For q = 1 To DeviceAmount

    Lastrow = Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Range("A" & Lastrow).Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Paste
    
Next


'Find the first empty row of the target sheet, and paste the order number into first empty B-column cell times the amount of devices'

Worksheets("Laskentapohja").Activate
OrderNr.Select
Selection.Copy

For q = 1 To DeviceAmount

    Lastrow = Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Range("B" & Lastrow).Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Paste
    
Next

'Find the first empty row of the target sheet, and paste the order date into first empty C-column cell times the amount of devices'

Worksheets("Laskentapohja").Activate
Paiva.Select
Selection.Copy


For q = 1 To DeviceAmount

    Lastrow = Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Range("C" & Lastrow).Activate
    Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Paste
    
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row`  instead of using `xldown`. It would be the same way as you used to find the last rows to paste. `Range("H2:H" & cells(rows.count,"H").end(xlup).row)`

Comment: Thank you, is there a reason I should use that instead of the solution I previously used?

Comment: If the xldown does not stop before the last row of the sheet, when you copy and paste it somewhere else, you will have too many rows copied and will not fit in the new paste range.

Comment: How about the use of PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, what breaks the functionality of that compared to just using .Paste? Other than that, code seems to work just fine. :)

Comment: what happens when you paste special values?

Comment: It gives me the "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed. That is, if I replace Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").Paste with Worksheets("Tilauslistaus").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: I don't see in the code pastespecial, but if I get this right, you are trying to pastespecial on the same line? `copy_rng.copy paste_rng.pastespecial` , pastespecial needs to be on a separate line.